# How to pass range to Excel formula from VBA function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm writing a [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) function to generate moving averages for smoothing a graph.  I need to use quartile ranges to adjust the smoothing formula.  How do I pass the QuartileRange to the `Evaluate` function to return the quartile value of that range so I may use it in my function?

The function is called as follows

```
=MovingAverageSmoothQuartile( A1, 4, B1:b10 )
```

Where

- `A1` is the value to smooth,
- `4` is the number of values to use and
- `B1:B10` is a column of samples used to calculate the quartile value.

  ```
  Function MovingAverageSmoothQuartile(r As Range, ByVal m As Integer, QuartileRange As Range)
  ' returns a smoothed average using the 'rectangular' method
  Dim q1 As Double, q2 As Double, q3 As Double        
  q1 = Evaluate("Quartile( " + QuartileRange.Text + ", 1") ' <--- Stuck here
  ```

Comment: What does `QuartileRange.Text` contain?

Comment: Should you not use & to concatenate the strings rahter than + ?

Comment: Thank you to all who answered.  When I get back to work I'll implement your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
q1 = WorksheetFunction.quartile(QuartileRange, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QUARTILE` directly in VBA without `EVALUATE`.

For example, to return the first quartile from A1:A10:

```
Sub Calltest()
MsgBox Test([a1:a10])
End Sub

Function Test(rng1 As Range)
Test = Application.WorksheetFunction.Quartile(rng1, 1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure why you would use `Evaluate` here? I think you need to do this instead:

```
ql = WorksheetFunction.Quartile(QuartileRange, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
q1 = Evaluate("Quartile(INDIRECT(" + QuartileRange.Text + "), 1")
```

I am sorry, I don't know the use of `Quartile` function & am assuming that the `QuartileRange.Text` contains a range address in string form.